# How to Configure Different EF Models For Different Tests for the same context?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I have an existing EF DbContext class (`SyncContext`) that is generated from a SQL database.  In my unit tests, I use SQLite to not have an external dependency on SQL.  Problem is the SQL database has tables without keys which SQLite will not allow.  In order to work around this I inherit from the `SyncContext` class (`TestSyncContext`), and override the `OnModelCreating` method and manually define fields as keys.  This was working great until I ran into an issue where I needed to have different keys for different tests, since I was testing having rows with duplicate values for the key column in the table (`DupKeyTest`).  I added a way to be able to define different keys in the `OnModelCreating` for each test.  When I run the tests individually, everything works fine.  When I run the test with other tests, it errors because the OnModelCreating isn't getting called with the different keys for the `DupKeyTest`.  I finally traced it down to the ServiceProviderCache caching the DbContextOptions, and resolved my issue by adding this code directly before my context.Database.EnsureCreated:

```
var field = ServiceProviderCache.Instance.GetType().GetField("_configurations", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var dict = (ConcurrentDictionary<IDbContextOptions, (IServiceProvider ServiceProvider, IDictionary<string, string> DebugInfo)>)field?.GetValue(ServiceProviderCache.Instance);
dict.Clear();
```

Is there a supported methodology to get this to work?  I was thinking that if I made the DBContextOptions unique, then I wouldn't have an issue with EF reusing the existing options and not calling `OnModelCreationg`, but I couldn't get that to work.

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 if it matters.